# Modifying a button's appearance without destroying StyleSheet settings established in Qt Creator

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qt-designer

The specific application is a Tic Tac Doe toy app made of a grid of 9 buttons. The original layout of the buttons is built in Qt Creator, where their large font is established by a styleSheet property.

When a winning row occurs, I want the main app to 'light up' that row of buttons, *without* it needing to be aware of the buttons' properties that were established in Qt Creator. I want to *modify* their styleSheets rather than just *set* them, so that the app retains the buttons' original properties, as well as in addition changing the background colour to green in this case.

Many related questions seem to deal with setting styleSheets, even setting them to different properties if the widget is activated, but not  with modifying them from existing settings.

Comment: @eyllanesc: The example is a trivial learning exercise but the answer is meant to show how an App can change the properties of a widget established in Qt Creator without needing to know those properties, and yet without destroying them.

Comment: Could be regarded as a duplicate of this question:  pyqt-way-to-read-a-widgets-stylesheet

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
def highlightButton(self, button):
    currentStyle = button.styleSheet()
    highlightStyle = 'background-color: lightgreen;'
    combinedStyleSheet = 'QPushButton {' + currentStyle + highlightStyle + '}'
    button.setStyleSheet(combinedStyleSheet)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if the button already has a 'background-color'. The new one will just over-ride it.